# Stuck in: npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut')

Tags: reactjs, npm, terminal, sharp

I am stuck in installing a library sharp with the command

```
npm install sharp
```

Every time I try a proposed solution on other forums it pretty much says the same thing of  "npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'edgesOut')." I even tried solving the other peer dependcy warnings but its the same deal. I feel stuck in this weird loop of not being able to uninstall/install anything.

Previously I was able to install things without a problem.

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fdV8.png)

I tried installing/uninstallig npm but when doing so I get the same error.
I checked for Turkish characters or if the directory path had special characters or spaces but it doesnt.